# Решено ошибка 404 на всех страницах Laravel кроме основой

Tags: php, laravel, битрикс

Мой сервис для B24 очень сильно разросся и хочу перенести его на Laravel, но с этим возникли проблемы.

Опишу пошагово. Создал проект, залил на портал (BitrixVM), мейн страница работает ('****/bx_laravel/')

В web.php

> Route::get('/', function () {
> return 'Работает'; });

Делаю любой другой роут. Возвращается страница портала с 404 от Битрикса, а не от Ларавела.

> Route::get('/test', function () {
> return 'Не работает'; });

Создаю в сервисе .htaccess с содержимым

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ / [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /home/bitrix/www/***/***/***/bx_laravel/public/index.php [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Теперь при заходе на ***/bx_laravel/что_угодно получаю 404 от Ларавела. Значит Index'ом от ларки обрабатывается, но что-то идёт не так.
Просьба подсказать дальнейшие шаги, чтобы и Битриксу не помешать, и решить 404 на Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока писал, понял, что ошибка в .htaccess, в таком варианте всё работает.

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond
%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```